# Installing puppetlabs/apt fails with '302 Found'

Tags: vagrant, puppet, vagrant-provision

So I have a vagrant / puppet setup for my project* and am running Ubuntu 14.04 on it. It just broke, without changing anything. `puppet module install puppetlabs-apt` inside the VM fails with the following lines:

```
Error: Could not execute operation for 'puppetlabs/apt'
The server being queried was https://forge.puppetlabs.com
The HTTP response we received was '302 Found'
Check the author and module names are correct.
```

I'm using this module for quite some time and it seems like it just stopped working for no reason. Any advice appreciated.

-- Edit: answer question
running it with --debug doesn't help much I guess

```
 Notice: Preparing to install into /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules ...
 Notice: Created target directory /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules
 Notice: Downloading from https://forge.puppetlabs.com ...
 Error: Could not execute operation for 'puppetlabs/apt'
 The server being queried was https://forge.puppetlabs.com
 The HTTP response we received was '302 Found'
 Check the author and module names are correct.
```

*Link: https://github.com/dwalldorf/owTracker
`vagrant up` / `vagrant ssh` and `puppet module install puppetlabs-apt`

Comment: run with --debug, any outputs?

Comment: see initial question update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed. You can check [FORGE-327](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/FORGE-327) for more information

Answer (score 1):

https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apt redirect to https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apt

you can force it to use the correct forge by appending `--module_repository https://forge.puppet.com/` so it will become

```
puppet module install puppetlabs-apt --module_repository https://forge.puppet.com/
```

not sure exactly why it wants to download from https://forge.puppetlabs.com at first place, you could check your `puppet.conf`

Comment: hum .. work from my side `Notice: Preparing to install into /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules ...
Notice: Downloading from https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apt ...
Notice: Installing -- do not interrupt ... /home/vagrant/.puppet/modules
└─┬ puppetlabs-apt (v2.2.2)
  └── puppetlabs-stdlib (v4.12.0)`

Comment: The URL shouldn't contain "puppetlabs/apt" at the end, I've submitted an edit to the answer to fix it. It should just be `https://forge.puppet.com/`

Comment: I've filed bugs with Puppet Labs (https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/FORGE-327) and Ubuntu (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/puppet/+bug/1594316) to see if it can be fixed on either side.

Comment: This should be fixed. You can check [FORGE-327](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/FORGE-327) for more information.

Comment: @JamesPogran yes, the problem is fixed. Rewrote that party and did the ppa thing manually, now I can use the clean way again. Thanks a lot! You are welcome to post this again as the answer to the question.