# Can't install Puppet modules, '302 Found', Win 8.1 64 running Ubuntu trusty 64 in Vagrant 1.8.4

Tags: module, vagrant, installation, puppet, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to `vagrant up` successfully, but I always end up with ah SSH non-zero exit status.  The real error I'm having is that **puppet won't install any modules**. It starts by trying to install stdlib, and fails there, and never recovers.

Here is the relevant part of a verbose error log:

```
==> default: Successfully installed librarian-puppet-2.2.3
==> default: 10 gems installed
==> default: Installing ri documentation for thor-0.19.1...
==> default: Installing ri documentation for librarianp-0.6.3...
==> default: Installing ri documentation for rsync-1.0.9...
==> default: Installing ri documentation for multipart-post-2.0.0...
==> default: Installing ri documentation for faraday-0.9.2...
==> default: Installing ri documentation for faraday_middleware-0.10.0...
==> default: Installing ri documentation for semantic_puppet-0.1.3...
==> default: Installing ri documentation for minitar-0.5.4...
==> default: Installing ri documentation for puppet_forge-2.2.1...
==> default: Installing ri documentation for librarian-puppet-2.2.3...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for thor-0.19.1...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for librarianp-0.6.3...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for rsync-1.0.9...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for multipart-post-2.0.0...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for faraday-0.9.2...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for faraday_middleware-0.10.0...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for semantic_puppet-0.1.3...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for minitar-0.5.4...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for puppet_forge-2.2.1...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for librarian-puppet-2.2.3...[0m
DEBUG ssh: Sending SSH keep-alive...
DEBUG ssh: stdout: Error executing puppet module install. Check that this command succeeds:
puppet module install --version 4.5.1 --target-dir /var/www/my-repository/puppet/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/puppetlabs-stdlib/4.5.1 --module_repository https://forge.puppetlabs.com --modulepath /var/www/my-repository/puppet/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/puppetlabs-stdlib/4.5.1 --module_working_dir /var/www/my-repository/puppet/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/puppetlabs-stdlib/4.5.1 --ignore-dependencies puppetlabs-stdlib
Error:
[1;31mError: Could not execute operation for 'puppetlabs/stdlib'
  The server being queried was https://forge.puppetlabs.com
  The HTTP response we received was '302 Found'
    Check the author and module names are correct.[0m

 INFO interface: info: Error executing puppet module install. Check that this command succeeds:
puppet module install --version 4.5.1 --target-dir /var/www/my-repository/puppet/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/puppetlabs-stdlib/4.5.1 --module_repository https://forge.puppetlabs.com --modulepath /var/www/my-repository/puppet/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/puppetlabs-stdlib/4.5.1 --module_working_dir /var/www/my-repository/puppet/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/puppetlabs-stdlib/4.5.1 --ignore-dependencies puppetlabs-stdlib
Error:
[1;31mError: Could not execute operation for 'puppetlabs/stdlib'
  The server being queried was https://forge.puppetlabs.com
  The HTTP response we received was '302 Found'
    Check the author and module names are correct.[0m
 INFO interface: info: ==> default: Error executing puppet module install. Check that this command succeeds:
==> default: puppet module install --version 4.5.1 --target-dir /var/www/my-repository/puppet/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/puppetlabs-stdlib/4.5.1 --module_repository https://forge.puppetlabs.com --modulepath /var/www/my-repository/puppet/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/puppetlabs-stdlib/4.5.1 --module_working_dir /var/www/my-repository/puppet/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/puppetlabs-stdlib/4.5.1 --ignore-dependencies puppetlabs-stdlib
==> default: Error:
==> default: [1;31mError: Could not execute operation for 'puppetlabs/stdlib'
==> default:   The server being queried was https://forge.puppetlabs.com
==> default:   The HTTP response we received was '302 Found'
==> default:     Check the author and module names are correct.[0m
[1;32m==> default: Error executing puppet module install. Check that this command succeeds:
==> default: puppet module install --version 4.5.1 --target-dir /var/www/my-repository/puppet/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/puppetlabs-stdlib/4.5.1 --module_repository https://forge.puppetlabs.com --modulepath /var/www/my-repository/puppet/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/puppetlabs-stdlib/4.5.1 --module_working_dir /var/www/my-repository/puppet/.tmp/librarian/cache/source/puppet/forge/forgeapi_puppetlabs_com/puppetlabs-stdlib/4.5.1 --ignore-dependencies puppetlabs-stdlib
==> default: Error:
==> default: [1;31mError: Could not execute operation for 'puppetlabs/stdlib'
==> default:   The server being queried was https://forge.puppetlabs.com
==> default:   The HTTP response we received was '302 Found'
==> default:     Check the author and module names are correct.[0m[0m
DEBUG ssh: Exit status: 1
ERROR warden: Error occurred: The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

How do I get around this error?  The issue seems to be networking related, or a problem with the actual puppet program.  The `302 Found` is really throwing me for a loop...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the same error if i ssh into my vagrant machine and try to manually `puppet module install` any modules.

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892134/installing-puppetlabs-apt-fails-with-302-found you could use `--module_repository https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apt` for now but seems like a more global issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved that problem running "puppet module install puppetlabs-apt --module_repository https://forge.puppet.com/"

Comment: Worked for me too!  I'm getting a 'stale file handle' error now, but progress is being made! Thanks.